# How to ask Neo4j to take cycles into account

Tags: neo4j, cypher

It seems Neo4j intentionally omits cycles so a query like:

```
MATCH (n1)-[:R]->(n2)<-[:R]-(n1)
RETURN n1, n2;
```

Always returns nothing unless there are two relations with type `R` between `n1` and `n2` (which is absolutely possible and a bad hack).

But I have a scenario in which this cycle might happen and it's desired:

```
MATCH (n1)-[:R]->(n2)<-[:R]-(n3)
RETURN n1, n2, n3;
```

In this query, `n1` and `n3` might be the same node or different ones and it all depends on the data (both are valid). One way to implement this is like:

```
MATCH (n1)-[:R]->(n2)
MATCH (n2)<-[:R]-(n3)
RETURN n1, n2, n3;
```

This last query will include all the paths even cycles and it's totally fine. But my case is even one level more complicated than this:

```
MATCH (n0)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n0)-[:R0]->(n1)-[:R]->(n2)<-[:R]-(n3)
RETURN n0, n1, n2, n3;
```

As we've seen before cycles are omitted in this queries so we have to break it down to two `OPTIONAL MATCH`es:

```
MATCH (n0)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n0)-[:R0]->(n1)-[:R]->(n2)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n2)<-[:R]-(n3)
RETURN n0, n1, n2, n3;
```

But this is not the same as before (if the other one worked). Here the second `OPTIONAL MATCH` might not return any path while the first one did. In other words, the two `OPTIONAL MATCH`es are independent.

So my question is: how can I implement the following query and get the cycles in the results?

```
MATCH (n0)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n0)-[:R0]->(n1)-[:R]->(n2)<-[:R]-(n3)
RETURN n0, n1, n2, n3;
```

I hope it's not too confusing!

**Why two `OPTIONAL MATCH`es is not the answer**

Consider the following nodes and relationships:

1. `CREATE (n0:S)-[:R]->(n1:R)<-[:R]-(n2:E)-[:R]->(n3:R:L);`
2. `CREATE (n0:S)-[:R]->(n1:R:L)<-[:R]-(n2:E);`
3. `CREATE (n0:S)-[:R]->(n1:R)<-[:R]-(n2:E);`

In above examples, here are the meaning of the labels (so you can relate to the problem):

- `:S` start node
- `:R` revision
- `:E` entity
- `:L` latest as in latest revision

In this example each record of data is represented in `:E`+`:R` and when the record is updated, a new `:R` is added to it. The current state of the data is labeled `:L` so we can find the latest revision.

Now, among the three given examples, the last one is invalid data since it does not have any `:L`. The first one has two revisions and the second one has one.

The requested query should:

1. Return `:S` regardless
2. Return all the entities and their latest revision, only if they have a latest revision
3. An entity without latest revision is meaningless, it should not be returned at all

This query would have returned the requested data if Neo4j supported cycles:

```
MATCH (n1:S)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n1)-[:R]->(n2:R)<-[:R]-(n3:E)-[:R]->(n4:R:L)
RETURN labels(n1), labels(n3), labels(n4);
```

The **expected results** for the above query are:

```
╒════════════╤════════════╤════════════╕
│"labels(n1)"│"labels(n3)"│"labels(n4)"│
╞════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│["S"]       │["E"]       │["R","L"]   │
├────────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│["S"]       │["E"]       │["R","L"]   │
├────────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│["S"]       │null        │null        │
└────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

But the **actual results** are:

```
╒════════════╤════════════╤════════════╕
│"labels(n1)"│"labels(n3)"│"labels(n4)"│
╞════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│["S"]       │["E"]       │["R","L"]   │
├────────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│["S"]       │null        │null        │
├────────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│["S"]       │null        │null        │
└────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

As you can see the second path is cut short because it included a cycle. Now if we use the two `OPTIONAL MATCH` approach:

```
MATCH (n1:S)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n1)-[:R]->(n2:R)<-[:R]-(n3:E)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n3)-[:R]->(n4:R:L)
RETURN labels(n1), labels(n3), labels(n4);
```

The results would be:

```
╒════════════╤════════════╤════════════╕
│"labels(n1)"│"labels(n3)"│"labels(n4)"│
╞════════════╪════════════╪════════════╡
│["S"]       │["E"]       │["R","L"]   │
├────────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│["S"]       │["E"]       │["R","L"]   │
├────────────┼────────────┼────────────┤
│["S"]       │["E"]       │null        │
└────────────┴────────────┴────────────┘
```

While the second case is fixed, the third case is now the problem and that's because the two optional clauses can exist independently.

Sorry for the long question, I tried to be brief!

Comment: Give an example of test data on which the first query returns nothing.

Comment: I updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, this query should give you the expected result table you're looking for:

```
MATCH (n1:S)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n1)-[:R]->(n2:R)<-[:R]-(n3:E)
WHERE (n3)-[:R]->(:R:L)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n3)-[:R]->(n4:R:L)
RETURN labels(n1), labels(n3), labels(n4)
```

The key is the WHERE we give to the first optional match. The OPTIONAL MATCH will only match if `n3` has the desired path to a `:R:L` node, and it will count relationships and nodes that were already traversed by the OPTIONAL MATCH.

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATED]

(A) New answer, based on new info in question.

```
MATCH (s:S)-[:R]->(firstRev:R)
OPTIONAL MATCH (firstRev)<-[:R]-(e:E)
OPTIONAL MATCH (e)-[:R]->(latestRev:L)
RETURN
  LABELS(s) AS ls,
  CASE WHEN latestRev IS NOT NULL THEN LABELS(e) END AS le,
  LABELS(latestRev) AS ll;
```

The above query uses 2 `OPTIONAL MATCH` clauses to allow a cycle (where the 2 `R` relationships are identical). The `CASE` clause will return a NULL `le` value if the second `OPTIONAL MATCH` failed.

(B) Original answer (obsolete)

Does this work for you?

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (n1)-[:R]->(n2)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n2)<-[:R]-(n3)
RETURN n1, n2, n3;
```

Comment: Please read the question to the end. I've already included your solution in my question and it's not the answer.

Comment: I do not see my solution in your question. (By the way, I fixed a minor typo in your sample data.) Try my solution on your sample data.

Comment: Yours is the same as the one with two `OPTIONAL MATCH`es in my question. And as I mentioned in the question, while two `MATCH`es are the same one, two `OPTIONAL MATCH`es are not the same as one.

Comment: It is NOT the same. Have you tested my solution?

Comment: I've updated the question, sorry it took long I hope it's not too long to discourage you.

Comment: Thank you for the update, yours is valid but the other one is just a better answer.

Answer (score 1):

1) You can correct the version with two "option" with adding checks for a match of nodes:

```
MATCH (n1:S)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n1)-[:R]->(n2:R)<-[:R]-(n3:E)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n3t)-[:R]->(n4:R:L) WHERE n3t = n3
RETURN labels(n1), labels(n3t), labels(n4);
```

2) I think you are wrong to use the term [`cycle`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycle_(graph_theory)), and this gives rise to the impression that you have something not right with the data model. On your test data no cycles:

[image]

Comment: I understand your second concern; since the graph is directional my data has got no cycles in it. But since neo4j traverse the graph regardless of the edge directions, then it means the graph is actually undirectional. And in an undirectional graph a-b-a is a cycle. It's just not a *simple cycle* but a *cycle* nevertheless. And thanks for the answer.

Comment: No, this is not a cycle: in cycle every relationship occurs only one time.

Comment: Please refer to the same link you've given. It is mentioned there: *A simple cycle may be defined either as a closed walk with no repetitions of vertices and edges allowed*. Your definition refers to simple cycles, cycles can have redundant nodes and edges.

Comment: Or you might be referring to a circuit: *A circuit can be a closed walk allowing repetitions of vertices but not edges; however, it can also be a simple cycle, so explicit definition is recommended when it is used.*. Your choice :)

Comment: @Mehran Yes you are right. By inertia closed walk I did not take as a cycle.