# How to ask Neo4j to take cycles into account in an optimised way

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is a follow-up question to:

[How to ask Neo4j to take cycles into account](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42059081/how-to-ask-neo4j-to-take-cycles-into-account)

In my previous question, @stdob-- kindly helped me find the following query:

```
MATCH (n1:S)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n1)-[:R]->(n2:R)<-[:R]-(n3:E)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n3t)-[:R]->(n4:R:L)
WHERE n3t = n3
RETURN labels(n1), labels(n3t), labels(n4);
```

The above query is a replacement for the following:

```
MATCH (n1:S)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n1)-[:R]->(n2:R)<-[:R]-(n3:E)-[:R]->(n4:R:L)
RETURN labels(n1), labels(n3t), labels(n4);
```

And I have to use the first one because in my data there's the possibility that `n2` and `n4` are the same nodes and since Neo4j refuses to take the same node twice, it will return null.

While the first query is valid and working, it has got a really bad performance. It forces the database to restart the search for the whole data and at the end, it will match the selected nodes using `n3t = n3`. Just to give you a hint on how bad its performance is, on a dataset of 200k magnitude, it takes 5 seconds to return the result while if I omit the second `OPTIONAL MATCH` and its `WHERE` the result is generated in less than 10 milliseconds for the same query. If anyone's interested, here's the execution plan for the query:

[image]

The right branch is the part I mentioned earlier (which I tried to fool Neo4j to take a node for the second time). As you can see 2M db hits were incurred in order to make Neo4j take a node for the second time. The actual query for this execution plan is:

```
PROFILE MATCH (n5_1:Revision:`Account`)<-[:RevisionOf]-(n5_2:Entity:`Account`) 
WITH n5_2, n5_1
ORDER BY n5_1.customer_number ASC
LIMIT 100
OPTIONAL MATCH (n5_1)-[:`Main Contact`]->(n4_1:Wrapper)<-[:Wrapper]-(:Revision:`Contact`)<-[:RevisionOf]-(n4_2:Entity:`Contact`) 
OPTIONAL MATCH (n4_4)-[:RevisionOf]->(n4_3:Revision:Latest:`Contact`:Active) 
WHERE (n4_2) = (n4_4) 
RETURN n5_1, n5_2, n4_1, n4_2, n4_3
```

So my question is, how can I write a Cypher query in which a node is taken for the second time while the performance is not gonna suffer?

For some example data and testbed, please go to the other question.

Comment: Have you considered writing a custom procedure for this? You might want to look at the code for APOC's [PathExplorer](https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-apoc-procedures/blob/3.1/src/main/java/apoc/path/PathExplorer.java) as a starting point. This will give you more control over traversal uniqueness, allowing you reuse edges during your traversal.

Comment: Your last OPTIONAL MATCH is a little odd, in that you're using a new variable `n4_4` here, but you have a where clause after saying it must be equal to `n4_2`. This optional match is the cause of your performance hit. If you use `n4_2` in this match instead, it should work. However in your linked question this gave some undesirable results, but it looks like it should be easy to filter the results you have to make sure `n_43` is not null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I posted on your linked question an answer that should give the result table you described. If that fits what you're looking for, this query uses the same approach, and may be the solution for this question:

```
PROFILE MATCH (n5_1:Revision:`Account`)<-[:RevisionOf]-(n5_2:Entity:`Account`) 
WITH n5_2, n5_1
ORDER BY n5_1.customer_number ASC
LIMIT 100
OPTIONAL MATCH (n5_1)-[:`Main Contact`]->(n4_1:Wrapper)<-[:Wrapper]-(:Revision:`Contact`)<-[:RevisionOf]-(n4_2:Entity:`Contact`)
WHERE (n4_2)-[:RevisionOf]->(:Revision:Latest:`Contact`:Active)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n4_2)-[:RevisionOf]->(n4_3:Revision:Latest:`Contact`:Active) 
RETURN n5_1, n5_2, n4_1, n4_2, n4_3
```

This keeps the `n4_2` in your last OPTIONAL MATCH, which should solve the performance issue you observed.

As you noted in your previous question, you want to avoid circumstances where the first OPTIONAL MATCH succeeds, but the second fails, leaving the variables as non-null from the first OPTIONAL MATCH when you don't want them to be.

We solve that issue by adding a WHERE after the first OPTIONAL MATCH, forcing the match to succeed only if the pattern you're looking for in the second OPTIONAL MATCH exists off of the last node (this will work even if such a pattern reuses relationships and nodes from the OPTIONAL MATCH).

Comment: Thank you, this solution is perfect.

Comment: Glad to hear it! When you get the chance, can you accept this answer?

Comment: Sorry I thought I did

Answer (score 1):

You can try collect the tail in additionally:

```
PROFILE 
MATCH (n1:S)
OPTIONAL MATCH (n1)-[:R]->(n2:R)<-[:R]-(n3:E)
WITH n1, [null] + ( (n3)-[:R]->(:R:L) ) as tail
WITH n1, tail, size(tail) as tailSize
UNWIND tail as t
WITH n1, tailSize, t WHERE (tailSize = 2 AND NOT t is NULL) OR tailSize = 1
WITH n1, nodes(t) as nds
WITH n1, nds[0] as n3t, nds[1] as n4
RETURN labels(n1), labels(n3t), labels(n4)
```